# In OpenAPI 3.0, how do I create a link from a list of entities to a single entity?

Tags: openapi, schemathesis

In most OpenAPI 3.0 documentation (like the [official one](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/links/)), links are introduced with a combination of a POST endpoint to create an entity returning an ID linking to a GET endpoint to fetch that entity by that same returned ID:

1. `POST /users -> UserID`
2. `GET /users/{UserID} -> User`

In Schemathesis context, this would assume an empty data storage and simulate a create+fetch scenario. I would like to test my `GET` endpoints on a pre-warmed data storage and implement a "fetch a list, then fetch each entity from the list by ID" scenario:

1. `GET /users -> List[User] -> List[UserID]`
2. `GET /users/{UserID} -> User` for each entry in the list

For this to work, I need an OpenAPI link from the list `GET` endpoint to the entity `GET` endpoint, however I can't seem to find either an example or a confirmation that this is indeed possible.

Can I and if so how can I create such a link in OpenAPI 3.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenAPI links are defined using [JSON Pointers](https://opis.io/json-schema/2.x/pointers.html). JSON Pointers are quite limited - they can only point to a specific field within a JSON Structure (such as "the first element of this array", or the entire array) and don't support wildcard expressions (such as "*any/each* element of this array").

This means, for example, that if you have the `GET /users` endpoint that returns

```json
[
  {
    "id": "29d590d1-02b2-4aa1-9ce5-98202cc9a619",
    "username": "nikolai",
    ...
  },
  {
    "id": "58091b14-eb06-47ee-b896-50cebdda20ef",
    "username": "helen",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

you can define a link like `$response.body#/0/id` to indicate that the `id` *of the first user* in the list can be used as a parameter to another endpoint. But there's no way for a link to reference *an arbitrary/each user* from the list.

You can check these discussions in the OpenAPI Specification repository for more details:

- [Link for array element](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1305)
- [Variables/Parameters in Links](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1327)